# Marionette.js Region's $el doesn't have modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, marionette

The error that I'm getting is from the last line in the onShow function:

```
    //modalregion: shows a modal detail view in bootstrap modal
var ModalRegion = Marionette.Region.extend({
    el: "#modal",

    onShow :  function(view) {
        view.on("close", this.hideModal,this);
        this.$el.modal('show'); //<- **throws TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'modal'** 
    },

    hideModal: function() {
        this.$el.modal('hide'); // bootstrap modal
    }
});
```

[I have seen other posts that have error with the same form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220670/unable-to-call-bootstrap-modal-window-using-javascript-in-chrome-works-in-firef)
Object [object Object] has no method 'XXXX'

Their solution was "stop loading jquery twice".  I'm using require.js so that shouldn't happen but I checked the Network tab on Crome Dev tools and nothing was loading twice.

this.$el is defined in the debugger but not with modal as a function:

```
this.$el: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init
0: div#modal
context: #document
length: 1
selector: "#modal"
...snip...
load: function ( url, params, callback ) {
map: function ( callback ) {
mousedown: function ( data, fn ) {
mouseenter: function ( data, fn ) {
mouseleave: function ( data, fn ) {
mousemove: function ( data, fn ) {
mouseout: function ( data, fn ) {
mouseover: function ( data, fn ) {
mouseup: function ( data, fn ) {
next: function ( until, selector ) {
```

Is there a step I'm missing?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region's `$el` is a jQuery selector object, and jQuery doesn't provide a `modal` function on this object without a plugin like jQueryUI or KendoUI or something else that would provide the modal functionality.

The plugin that provides the `modal` function is not being loaded in to your page. You'll need to require that plugin.

Comment: Hi Derick, I read your post on modals: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/17/managing-a-modal-dialog-with-backbone-and-marionette/

Comment: I didn't see in your modal post how the modal function gets set/loaded.  I've been searching all day but to no avail.  Could you please show how to load twitter-bootstrap modal into Marionette?  I found how to shim the bootstrap file but I'm not sure how to use the shim.  Thanks.  Andrew

Comment: This link has an example. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/requirejs/bootstrap$20modal/requirejs/KdyGl3T52Lw/di22ni7lVXwJ  Thanks Derick